# Refresh a <li> with php code inside

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have this code:

```
<li class="dropdown">
    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" title="Alerts">
        <i class="fa fa-bell fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i><?php number_of_alerts($emailOfTheLoggedInUser); ?><br/><br/>
        <span class="caret"></span>
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><?php echo alerts($emailOfTheLoggedInUser); ?></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

I need to refresh functions `number_of_alerts($emailOfTheLoggedInUser)` and `alerts($emailOfTheLoggedInUser)`every 5 seconds, this functions makes a query to mysql database and bring back a number and a description of the alert, I already try with several suggestions but anything works. Your help will really be appreciated.

Comment: Use ajax to update the value.

Comment: PHP executes on the server side; the php code inside the `<?php` and `?>` tags can't be reinterpreted without a page reload. To keep the current code and make it work (in a terribly ugly way) you'd have to reload the entire page every 5 seconds. What you want to do instead is use JavaScript to get that info every 5 seconds (using an Ajax call).

Comment: As PHP is server side language, you can not execute and rerender on client side, Therefore you have option of:

AJAX: Short but you have to repeat after interval of time, this can bring  unnecessary load on your server..(One way Communication - Client to Server)

SSE(ServerSide Events): In This server sents client information whenever there is one.(One way Communication - Server to client)

WebSockets: In This server sents client information whenever there is one or client can as information whenever its is required.(Two way Communication)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `jQuery.ajax()` or something similar to make server calls to your `php` pages that run `alerts($emailOfTheLoggedInUser);` and `number_of_alerts($emailOfTheLoggedInUser);` functions.

Comment: That was correct, I change the PHP code from a function file to a new php file and I call it using a JavaScript function and it works

Answer (score 0):

```
`<?php number_of_alerts($emailOfTheLoggedInUser); ?>`
```

The above function is php code and php is server side scripting language. If you want to reload this function after specific time period then you have to reload the whole web page. 
To reload the web page after 5 second the code is written below.

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5">
</head>
```

Put this code in head section of page.